# How can I display name of User object in ProfileViewController

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, uikit

I need to display user.username on Text in ProfileView but I got error when I try to fill current user with User. I have to get User in currentUser var.

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase

class AuthViewModel: ObservableObject
{
    @Published var userSession: FirebaseAuth.User?
    @Published var currentUser: User?
    
    private var tempUserSession: FirebaseAuth.User?
    private let service = UserService()
    
    init()
    {
        self.userSession = Auth.auth().currentUser
    }
    
    func login(withEmail email: String, password: String)
    {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { authResult, error in
            if let e = error
            {
                print(e.localizedDescription)
            }
            else
            {
                guard let user = authResult?.user else {return}
                self.userSession = user
                guard let uid = self.userSession?.uid else { return }
                self.service.fetchUser(withUid: uid)
                print("Did User log IN")
            }
        }
    }
    func fetchUser()
    {
        guard let uid = self.userSession?.uid else { return }
        service.fetchUser(withUid: uid) { user in <----- HERE I GOT AN ERROR Extra trailing closure passed in call
            self.currentUser = user
        }
    }
}
```

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import SwiftUI

class ProfileViewController: UIViewController
{
    var authViewModel = AuthViewModel()
    @IBOutlet weak var userNameLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        userNameLabel.text = authViewModel.currentUser?.username // HERE I WANT TO DISPLAY CURRENT USER - USERNAME
        print(userNameLabel.text)
        
    }
}
```

I tried fill currentuser with user but nothings worked. Still in profile view controller I got nill. (currentUser.username = nil)

Comment: Please share the details of "UserService".

Comment: I am with @mucahid-erdogan. But the code in the question is a bit confusing - the auth closure is calling this `self.service.fetchUser(withUid: uid)` which does not appear to be this `func fetchUser()` or maybe it is. If so then what is this `service.fetchUser(withUid: uid)` and why are you calling fetch user when you already have the user from the auth closure? `guard let user = authResult?.user` why don't you just load the user there instead of jumping through all those calls?

Comment: How can I load User in ProfileViewController?

Answer (score 0):

The code calls `fetchUser` like it's an asynchronous function and it's not; it's a synchronous function that does not return a value, nor has an escaping completion handler. So that's the cause of the error.

Here's how I would do it. Start with a a simple user class

```
class MyUser {
    var userName = ""
    var uid = ""
}
```

and then a simplified `fetchUser` using async/await

```
func fetchUser() {
    Task {
        let uid = "uid_0"
        let foundUser = await self.getUserAsync(withUid: "uid_0")

        print(foundUser.userName)
    }
}
```

and then the code to fetch the user from Firestore, instantiate a MyUser object and return it

```
func getUserAsync(withUid: String) async -> MyUser {
    let usersCollection = self.db.collection("users") //self.db points to my firestore
    let thisUserDoc = usersCollection.document(withUid)
    let snapshot = try! await thisUserDoc.getDocument()

    let user = MyUser()
    user.userName = snapshot.get("userName") as? String ?? "No Name"
    user.uid = withUid

    return user
}
```